# Помогите написать критерий поиска

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee, hibernate, jpa

Мне необходимо написать критерий поиска для следующей ситуации:

Есть 3 таблицы: таблица A, B и C.

Таблица А содержит следующие поля:

```
id - pk
name
```

Таблица B содержит следующие поля:

```
id - pk
type
```

Таблица C содержит следующие поля:

```
id - pk (fk1_fk2)
a_id (fk на таблицу А)
b_id (fk на таблицу B)
```

таблица C содержит связи где множество записей из таблицы A принадлежат одной записи в таблице B (ManyToOne), вопрос как мне получить все записи из таблицы A которые связанны с id из таблицы B, зная только id записи из таблицы B?

Использую Hibernate 4.3.8 и JPA.

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, в Ваш вопрос код, который демонстрирует Ваши попытки решить эту задачу, с указанием, что не получилось

Comment: в том то и дело что я только начал изучать и не знаю с чего начать. мой код:  `Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class).add( ? );` мой вопрос состоит в том что нужно писать в .add() ?

Comment: Причём тут jpa, если используете api hibernat? В jpa нет вот этого `Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria`. Там немного по другому. И привели бы свои классы, чтобы всем было ясно как они отображаются на таблицы (или таблицы на них).